# На мобильном устройстве код не работает

Tags: javascript, html, css

почему этот кусок кода не работает на мобильных устройствах.
Даже когда захожу через консоль в мобильный режим всё срабатывает, а на телефоне нет.

Пробовал использовать разные события, всё равно не могу изменить скрол страницы.

```
const punct = document.querySelectorAll('.text-dark');
        punct.forEach((item, i) => {
            
            item.addEventListener("touchstart", () => {

                document.documentElement.scrollTop = i * 53 + 1320;

            });

        });
```

Comment: а у вас на мобильном устройстве какой браузер и какой версии работает?https://caniuse.com/queryselector

Comment: вы можете по этой инструкции (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging) подключить свой телефон к девтулзе и посмотреть на каком методе ломается код